# C# Regex getting words that start with?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I use a regular expression to get words that start with `!` `?` For example `!Test`.

I tried this but it doesn't give any matches:

```
@"\B\!\d+\b"
```

Although it did work when I replaced the `!` with `$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:    ^!\w+

```
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches (inputText, @"^!\w+");

 foreach (Match  match in matches)
 {
      Console.WriteLine (match.Value);
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, it actually does work. I had to set the RegexOptions to multi-line.
Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: you had to use Multiline? what does your regex string and what you want to match look like?

Comment: The input text is a multi-line textbox, I want the output to be an array with all words that start with !. But it works now, good.

Comment: Careful, it will only match words at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that your regex was quite OK already, you just need to use `\w` (alphanumeric character) instead of `\d` (digit):

```
@"\B!\w+\b"
```

will match any word that is immediately preceded by a `!` unless that `!` itself is preceded by a word itself (that's what the `\B` asserts). Using a `^` instead will limit the matches to words that start at the beginning of a line which might not be what you want.

So this will match all the words including exactly one preceding `!` in this line:

```
!hello !this ...!will !!!be !matched!
```

but none of the words in this line:

```
this! won't!be matched!!!
```

You could also drop the `\B` altogether if you don't mind matching `!that` in `this!that`.

Comment: +1 Good catch Tim! This is the real answer. Unfortunately, I answered before the full domain of the problem was made clear.