# Get regex of words that starts with @ sign

Tags: javascript, regex

All answers that I found get rough solution for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041912/regex-to-find-words-that-start-with-u) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952032/c-sharp-regex-getting-words-that-start-with) ( /\b@\w+\b/gi ) is cover not only the "@abcdef" but "abc@abcdf" too, but what I need is a regex that match all words that starts with "@" sign and more than 6 characters length and non of following solutions give me what I need

```
/@\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}\b/gi
/\b@[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}\b/gi
```

Examples that should be matched:

```
@abcdefjh
```

Examples that shouldn't be matched:

```
abc@absdefgh
```

Added:
PS: Is there a way to improve this question that it can be more helpful for not experienced users like me?

Comment: Could you please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question(I haven't down voted it).

Comment: Your example answers are C#

Comment: What about `#*$@abc123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\B` before the @, not `\b`  - the `\b` is at the end of the word

> - `\b` Matches at a position that is followed by a word character but not preceded by a word character, or that is preceded by a word character but not followed by a word character.
> - `\B` Matches at a position that is preceded and followed by a word character, or that is not preceded and not followed by a word character.

More than 6 in total, use `,5` if 6 including the @ is ok

`\B@[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}\b`

https://regex101.com/r/QcLNw6/3

Comment: You right, just missed the difference between \b and \B, I need a little bit more experience :)

Comment: So, just to confirm, you need \B because @ is _not_ a word character, and to match an @ just after a space, \B works because it matches a non-word-boundary, is that correct? <https://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html>

Comment: @RichardWelsh Yes, that is the case here. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = [
    '@abcdefjh',
    '@abc',
    'abc@absdefgh',
    '#*$@abc123',
    'abc123',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ' :' + /(?:\s|^)@[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}/.test(a);
}));
```

---

If your browser supports it, you can use a negaitve lookbehind:

```
/(?<!\S)@[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}/
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I wanted to use a negative lookbehind but my Firefox doesn't support it :(

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match a word (consisted of word characters as in regular expressions) *preceded by an '@' and composed of more than 6 characters*.

```
@\w{6,}
```

Comment: That would find `@this123454`  in `this@this123454` too

Comment: Not exactly, that would match `@this123454`.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant - so not what OP wants